# enunciate-maven-plugin fails to compile class with generic type

Tags: java, maven, enunciate

I'm updating a legacy project using java 8 and enunciate-maven-plugin version 2.13.0. I have updated to jdk 11 and enunciate-maven-plugin 2.15.1 and since this I have encountered problems.

parent-pom

```
<profile>
    <id>jax-rs-api</id>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.webcohesion.enunciate</groupId>
            <artifactId>enunciate-core-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${enunciate-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.webcohesion.enunciate</groupId>
                <artifactId>enunciate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>docs</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

When the plugin is run by maven upon deploy, the following dto is not correctly compiled.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  26.953 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-19T10:44:33+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.webcohesion.enunciate:enunciate-maven-plugin:2.15.0:docs (default) on project my-project: Compile failed of Java JSON client-side classes. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.webcohesion.enunciate:enunciate-maven-plugin:2.15.0:docs (default) on project my-project: Compile failed of Java JSON client-side classes.
```

dto in question:

```
public abstract class IdentityView<T> {

    private String accountId;
    private T profile;
    private ConfigurationView configuration;

    // setters & getters
}
```

errors:

```
C:\...\my-project\target\enunciate\java-json-client\src\com\my-project\data\view\IdentityView.java:21: error: illegal start of type
  private ? _profile;
          ^
C:\...\my-project\target\enunciate\java-json-client\src\com\my-project\data\view\IdentityView.java:21: error: <identifier> expected
  private ? _profile;
                    ^
C:\...\my-project\target\enunciate\java-json-client\src\com\my-project\data\view\IdentityView.java:45: error: illegal start of type
  public ? getProfile() {
         ^
C:\...\my-project\target\enunciate\java-json-client\src\com\my-project\data\view\IdentityView.java:45: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
  public ? getProfile() {
           ^
C:\...\my-project\target\enunciate\java-json-client\src\com\my-project\data\view\IdentityView.java:53: error: illegal start of type
  public void setProfile(? _profile) {
Any ideas ?
```

I have no idea why enunciate is ignoring the generic T used at the class level and replacing it with a '?' within the getter and setters that it generates...

Many thanks in advance!